# Echo "row 1" content," row 2" content for each different position

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I want to do is kind of confusing and I'm not really good at English, so I'll post the code here first, so you can easily understand:

Here is the form content:

```
<select name="options[1][]" id="perso_1" class="multiselect required-entry product-custom-option" title=""  onchange="displayCondition()">
    <option value="0" disabled>Testing for Stackoverflow</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

And here is the function:

```
<script language="javascript">

    function displayCondition() {
        condition = new Array("","echo 'Option 1 chosen';","echo 'Option 2 chosen';", "");
        var getsel = document.getElementById('perso_1').value;
        document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
    }

</script>
```

Here are my vars:

```
$getperso = "SELECT * FROM perso";
$persoresult = mysqli_query($connection, $getperso) or die("Erro!: " . mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($persoresult);
```

Explaination: When the user chooses "Option1", it will echo under the form "Option 1 chosen", as I wrote in the script. The problem is that I got some content in my MySQL database table `perso` to write here instead of "Option 1 Chosen". I want the user to see the `perso_name` corresponding to the selected option.

I can't just echo every row with a `while` loop, because if I do that, the user will see every `perso_name` of each row when he chooses "Option 1".
I'm looking for something like " echo'$row_1['perso_name']" or something like that, but not with 300 lines of code for each option.

Thank you and sorry if it's not clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an ID for each "perso" in your database. The ID would be identical to the value of the select option. And than use a query like this and echo after:

```
$getperso = "SELECT perso_name FROM perso where id=$id";
```

and you will get the $id with :

```
var getsel = document.getElementById('perso_1').value;
```

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I'm quite a beginner here so i have some questions to understand your code. First, my variable "id" is already defined by the user's one, and how can we put "id=$id" if we never defined "$id" ? And the second one is that i also have to display the description and the image of the character, so i guess your method is not working in the case i have multiple things to echo ? Thanks :)

Comment: Alright, than try to get there from a different point of view. You would like to do something like [this?](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_database)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's exactly what i want :D The script is a little bit confusing for me but i'll try to adapt for my page, thanks you !

Comment: Hmm, excuse me for the late answer, but what does "  xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.asp?q="+str, true);" mean ?

Comment: It's called AJAX request. You sending a request to the getcostumers.asp file in the background with get method. Also you are sending the value of str in the q GET variable. It's also working with php extension not just asp. Make sure you learn about GET and POST methods to get a full understanding.